# How to create/control parallel worker?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a python program that does some work on a SQL database. I want to create some multithreading workers to handle the connection with the database. I've searched for solutions like `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but I need to control to what worker the job is assigned to.

Useful info:

- Each job will only access a single table.
- Jobs for the same table can't run simultaneously.
- Jobs are created asynchronously.

I'm looking for suggestions on how I can accomplish this or how to change the logic of my code.

**EDIT:**
For context I made a simplified version of the code I have:

```py
async def UpdatePlayer(profile_id):
    # retrieve data from website
    # computation on said data
    database_edit_row(args)

async def ShowPlayer(profile_id):
    database_get_row(args)
    print(data)
```

In reading a comment I've thought of making a new worker for each guild but I think it wont scale well since I plan to have this working with hundreds of users simultaneously.

Comment: post your code for better understand

Comment: You can pass arguments to the worker function to control what it does.